# How to select a specific date or a max date in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Greetings I need to select a specific date and if the specific date does not match I need to select the max, I'm no expert in SQL this is what I achieved so far but is returning all records:

```sql
select
    scs.subscription_id,
    case
        when scs.end_date = max(scs.end_date) then max(scs.end_date)
        when scs.end_date = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000Z' then '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000Z'
    end as end_date
from
    sim_cards sc
inner join sim_card_subscriptions scs on
    sc.id = scs.sim_card_id
where
    scs.subscription_id = 1
group by
    scs.end_date,
    scs.subscription_id
```

Comment: Looks like you use the timestampz type for sim_card_subscriptions.end_date, correct? Assuming you have 2 subscriptions ending on the same date but different time, then both IDs should appear with the same date trimmed to DAY?

Comment: A sample dataset from sim_card_subscriptions table would be helpful

Comment: maybe you should use `HAVING`

Comment: My guess is that "select a specific date and if the specific date does not match I need to select the max" has to be done per each row individually. A window function like `max(..) over(...)` might serve better

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want that (match a date X or use MAX) policy to be applied for each row individually and the MAX has to be calculated only across related subscriptions (sharing the same sim_card_id) so that you can use `max(end_date::date) over(partition by sim_card_id)` window function in your CASE statement to fallback to MAX if the specific date is not matched.

Consider the following sample dataset

```
with data (id, sim_card_id, end_date) as (
    values
        (1, 1, '2021-08-05 20:21:00'),
        (2, 1, '2021-10-10 12:12:10'),
        (3, 1, '2021-12-11 00:11:14'),  
        (4, 2, '2021-12-14 09:08:45'),
        (5, 2, '2021-12-14 15:42:07'),
        (6, 3, '2021-10-09 20:20:33')
)

select 
    id, 
    case 
        when end_date::date = '2021-10-10' then end_date::date
        else max(end_date::date) over(partition by sim_card_id) 
    end as end_date
from data
```

which yields the following output:

```
1   2021-12-11 -- max across sim_card ID=1
2   2021-10-10 -- matches desired date
3   2021-12-11 -- max across sim_card ID=1
4   2021-12-14 -- max across sim_card ID=2
5   2021-12-14 -- max across sim_card ID=2
6   2021-10-09 -- matches desired date
```